# How to access individual elements from a prop object in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue and studied the other questions here and can not seem to work out how to pass an object to a child component and reference individual elements of that object.  I want all elements of the object to be able to be individually accessed and used in the footer template where appropriate.
I am using NPM from node-js and run the dev with npm run dev

In my root component, App.Vue, I have as follows: (unrelated lines omitted)

```js
<template>
<div>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <bbay-footer v-bind:footerData="footerData"></bbay-footer>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Footer from './Components/SiteWide/Footer.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    'bbay-footer': Footer,
  },
  data() {
    return {
        footerData: [{
                titleFooter: 'My Computer Support',
                mainNumber: '0411111111',
                otherNumber: '0400000000',
                emailUs: 'mailto:info@mycomputersupport.com'
      }]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now in Footer.vue I have:

```js
<template>
  <footer>
   <p>{{startCR}} - {{copyright}} </p>
  </footer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    titleFooter: String,
    mainNumber: Number,
    otherNumber: Number,
    emailUs: String
  },

  data () {
    return {
      copyright: "Copyright 2020: ",
      startCR: this.footerData.titleFooter,
      mNum: footerData.mainNumber,
      oNum: footerData.otherNumber,
      emailUs: footerData.emailUs
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You just need to remove the `footerData` to be `this.titleFooter`, `this.mainNumber` etc. And actually remove the square brackets that wrap the actual data, unless they are meant to be in array?

Comment: Thanks Yom, sadly that did not fix the issue.  The copyright text now appears after removing footerData but not the string from startCR.

Comment: why you used `footerData` an array in App.Vue?

Comment: @JinalSomaiya not sure what you mean, but it is just a name I choose.  Are you asking why I am using an array as I am not intending too?  My intent is to wrap several strings and numbers in an object and then have them available to child components.  Happy to redo my code once I understand how to do it correctly.

Comment: ok. then use `footerData` as an object in App.vue file.

Comment: Jose provided the solution and it works correctly.  I was confused about whether I had to pass an array or object, but it now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing just 1 prop `footerData` but you have defined 4 in `Footer.vue`. Just define 1 prop in `Footer.vue`, and access as `this.footerData[0].titleFooter, ...`

```
export default {
 props: {
   footerData: Array,
 },

 data () {
   return {
     copyright: "Copyright 2020: ",
     startCR: this.footerData[0].titleFooter,
     mNum: this.footerData[0].mainNumber,
     oNum: this.footerData[0].otherNumber,
     emailUs: this.footerData[0].emailUs
   }
 },
}
```

You can handle the array in `Footer.vue`. You should define as many `props` as `v-bind` you are sending. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

Comment: This would work, but why put them in array when there should probably be only a single occurence of the individual props?

Comment: Hi Yom, agreed, but the question was to work out how to send more than one element down to a child component and Jose answered it perfectly.  It now works.