# Passing Custom Event back to child component through prop array in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to update a child component element through a custom event and know I am getting back to the root component as an alert gives me the current date and time, but I can not update the child component through the prop.   This is a follow on question to this [question and answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917451/how-to-access-individual-elements-from-a-prop-object-in-vue)

(irrelevant code omitted)

In my child component I have as follows:

```js
<template>
<div id="bar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h3>Timestamp Page Loaded: </h3>
      <h3>{{currentTime}}</h3>
    </div>
  <div class="column">
      <button v-on:click="update()">Click to get Current Timestamp</button>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    barData: Array
  },

  data() {
    return {
      callNow: this.barData[0].callNow,
      currentTime: this.barData[0].currentDT,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update: function () {
        const today = new Date();
        const date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
        const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        const dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
        this.$emit('newDateTime', dateTime)
    }
  }, 
}
</script>
```

And in my root component I have as follows:

```js
<template>
<div>
  <bbay-bar v-bind:barData="barData" v-on:newDateTime='upDateTime($event)'></bbay-bar>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Bar from './Components/SiteWide/Bar.vue'
export default {
  components: {
       'bbay-bar': Bar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
        barData: [{
        callNow: '0411111111',
        currentDT: '',
      }],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    upDateTime: function (update){
      //this.$alert(update, “thus so far“);
      this.currentDT = update;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `props` to initialize `data` in the child component, then using those values in the child component's template. Changes to `props` afterwards won't affect the child component's `data`, so the template isn't updated. This scenario is brought up in the Vue docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow).

If you don't require an array for `barData`, I'd recommend making it an object so your `data` look like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    barData: {
      callNow: '0411111111',
      currentDT: '',
    },
  }},
```

Then in the child component you could pass the prop like so:

```
props: {
  barData: Object
},
```

When you use the value in the child component, it'd then look like this:

```
<h3>{{ barData.currentDT }}</h3>
```

One thing I noticed is that in the `upDateTime` function you are updating `this.currentDT`. Previously your `data` property had a `barData` array with an object that has a field named `currentDT`, so this method wasn't updating the correct field. Given that `barData` is changed to an object, the method should be changed to update `this.barData.currentDT`